# Highchart Min Max for y-axis per series

Tags: highcharts

i have a highchart with 4 series. I also only set the min value for each y-axis to 0 cause there arent any negative values possible. now highchart is calculating the max value by itself what is nice BUT i need this for each series itself. The reason is that i have 2 series with very high values from the range up to 5000 and the other two values are relativ small from 0 to 50. 
The max value highcharts calculates is used for all four series - so the chart looks like this:
[image]

As you can see you can only see the two high value series - the other two arent really visible at the bottom of the chart.
When i disable the two series with the high values the chart looks nice for the other two values:
[image]

is there any flag i can use so highchart will calculate the max value / scale per series? Or have i really calculate it by myself - also on zoom and so on.
I found this: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4248
But i thought thats some basic functionality with is needed very often so there has to be something..

greetings

Comment: Each series can use a different yAxis. Create 2 different yAxis( 1:0 to 2000 / 2: 0to 80) and the chart will adapt.

Comment: okay but is there no functionality from highcharts itself to scale the yAxis by itself per series?

Comment: There is, but each series needs a seperate yAxis, just like @Core972 says. You can't show wildly different values on top of each other in the same axis. It makes no sense. Example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

Comment: okay i understood this. but i already have a yAxis for each series - but i only set the min to 0 and the title (unit for the serie) like you can see in the images.

Comment: okay my fault... i created four yAxis but added them all to the first one. thanks to  the answers

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be better to use `logarithmic` axis type? Your chart would have only one axis adjusted to much difference between the values of series points. When it comes to differences between units of measurement, always you can set the different `tooltip.pointFormat` definition for specific series.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 20, 30, 22, 16, 32, 45, 24, 11, 2],
        pointStart: 1,
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.y} km/h</b>'
        }
    }, {
        data: [4500, 3450, 4242, 2348, 5216, 3212, 4564, 3128, 5256, 4512],
        pointStart: 1,
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.y} kW/h</b>'
        }
    }]
});
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/bfnj4mp8/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.tooltip.pointFormat